# How to debug 'this' using arrow functions (fat arrow) with ES6 and WebStorm...?

Tags: ecmascript-6, webstorm

How to debug `this` using arrow functions (fat arrow) with ES6 and WebStorm...?
as currently with latest version when I reefer to `this.XXXX` I can not view the value of `XXXX`. I have to resort to the hack of:

```
var self = this;
```

in order to debug arrow functions ES6 with JetBrains WebStorm

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit more?

Comment: It looks like you mis-use the `debug` term.

Comment: not it seems that it is a bug in Chrome but WebStorm just did a patch for it

Answer (score 2):

Tx to Vlad in latest WebStorm EA beta you can finally debug 'this' properties on arrow functions.. to enable you need to go to Registry in WebStorm see image below:

[image]

and with this patch, you will be able to debug as you normally would functions, but inside arrow functions...

Credit Vlad from the WebStorm team for adding this