# WebStorm class properties undefined when debugging TypeScript arrow functions

Tags: typescript, webstorm, arrow-functions

Whenever I debug a lambda expression (arrow function) in WebStorm (2016.1.3) my class properties are `undefined`.
I know that in JS `this` becomes `_this` in the transpiled code. I can manually add a watch, which uses `_this` instead of `this` but that is rather cumbersome.

I read ([How to debug 'this' using arrow functions (fat arrow) with ES6 and WebStorm...?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36274069/how-to-debug-this-using-arrow-functions-fat-arrow-with-es6-and-webstorm)) that there was a fix but I cannot find the registry entries shown in the answer.

Can somebody please help?

Comment: What do you mean by "I cannot find the registry entries" ? As far as I can see they are there (although I have used PhpStorm to check that).

Comment: The poster says "go to Registry in WebStorm" but I cannot find one in 2016.1.3. I tried to find a few of the listed ones in regedit (Windows) but couldn't find them in the system registry. I only have Webstorm installed. Can you please point me in the right direction?

Comment: Just found it. It can be opened by going to Help, Find Action, then enter registry. Checking the one mentioned in the post does indeed fix the issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Can somebody please help

There is no fix at the moment. You can track it here : https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/2859

Comment: This is only marginally related. Apparently there is a fix for it in Webstorm and that is what my question is about.

Answer (score 0):

Changing the registry didn't solve it for me. (It was already checked.)
But changing the arrow function to a bind function did work. Not so elegant though.

Example loading via a Promise:

Change

`file.load().then(() => { ... })`
to

`file.load().then(function() { ... }.bind(this))`